# Custom high order function for Scala sequence via implicits?

Tags: scala

We want a List back, when called on a list, and a Seq on a Seq.

```
implicit class SeqWithMyFilter[+T](seq: Seq[T]) {
  def myFilter(pred: T => Boolean): Seq[T] = seq.filter(pred)
}

scala> List("x").myFilter(_=="x")
res1: Seq[String] = List(x)
```

But adding types doesnt compile:

```
implicit class SeqWithMyFilter[+T, +U <: Seq[T]](seq: U) {
  def myFilter(pred: T => Boolean): U = seq.filter(pred)
}
```

... since seq.filter(pred) always returns a Seq...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use is `SeqLike` such that:

```
implicit class SeqWithMyFilter[A, Repr <: SeqLike[A, Repr]](seq: Repr){
  def myFilter(pred: A => Boolean): Repr = seq filter pred
}
```

Because the definition of `filter` is defined in terms of the implementing class:

```
abstract def filter(pred: T => Boolean): Repr
```

Take a look at [TraversableLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L1). You'll find out that `List`, `Seq` and many (not all) of those that inherit or mixin `Traversable` are implemented in terms of `SeqLike`.

Comment: thanks, with this I get: Seq("x").myFilter(_=="x") error: value myFilter is not a member of Seq[String]

Comment: @andersbohn Sounds like it's not picking up the `implicit` in the scope of where you're calling it.

Comment: but I just paste it into the REPL, the first example in my question works fine (with Seq[T]), but it seems (Repr) is not matched by the compiler... I'll try to tinker with it, thou :)

Comment: @andersbohn might require a `CanBuildFrom`